# Laravel Trying to Call Model Class Returns Not Found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

This is in my routes.php :

```
Route::post('/', function()
{

$rules = array(
'email' => 'required|email'
);


$validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);


if ($validation->fails())
{
echo "Not a valid e-mail";
} 
else
{
$subscriber = Subscriber::where('email','=', Input::get('email') );

if ($subscriber) 
{
    echo "Email already exists";
}

else
{
    Subscriber::create(array(
        'email' => Input::get('email')
        ));
```

In my models folder, I have the following class defined:

```
<?php 

class Subscriber extends Eloquent {
protected $table = 'subscribers';
protected $fillable = array('email');
public $timestamps = false;
}

 ?>
```

When I try and insert information into the database, it's telling me that Class 'Subscriber' is not found. Am I missing a connection of some sort?

Comment: What is your model name ?

Comment: remove the 's' from your model name to Subscriber.php. File & class name must match. If your class is Subscriber than your model name should be Subscriber too.

Comment: Sensitive. Just renamed to Subscriber.php and re run the code and report the result.

Comment: Sometimes in framework, code fail if your model name and Class name in your model not exactly same. Im sure your model name causing this.

Comment: It worked, but it still echoes out "Email already exists" even if it's not in the database.

Comment: rather than echo "Email already exists"; use var_dump($subscriber) and see what u get.

Comment: I get the Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder object.

Comment: I got it to work by adding ->first() to the ORM.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you run `composer dumpautoload` when you create your model, so Laravel knows the new class exists.

Class files are automatically pulled in based on your autoload.php file.  This file is dynamically generated via composer.  You only have to run this once each time you create a new class file.  If you modify an existing one, it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan dump-autoload`. It will regenerate all class files and class loader

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to resurrect an old thread. You need to make sure that the file imports the class. Do this by adding the following line to the top of your routes.php file:

```
use App\Subscriber;
```

Note: This assumes that your generated class is in the App folder, which is the default.